# QuickBlox not sending APNS

Tags: ios7, apple-push-notifications, quickblox, udid

Suddenly I'm getting an error when sending APNS through QuickBlox, and it's so weird cause it was working pretty well before.

After user is logged i'm using TRegisterSubscriptionWithDelegate to register it for APNS, when sending APNS the error is

> No recipients. At least one user should be subscribed for APNS (Apple
>   Push) (through SDK or REST API)

Thought it could be something inside my app but when trying to send APNS in admin panel, got the same error:

[image]

I've uploaded .p12 certificate and it's valid.

Have no idea what may be happening. Anyone could show me a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve checked it and for sure that’s the problem. All my devices are being added with same UDID: 02:00:00:00:00:00 despite they have their correct UDID on Apple Developer’s portal.

[image]

From [iOS 7 pre release](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html):

> In iOS 7 and later, if you ask for the MAC address of an iOS device,
>   the system returns the value 02:00:00:00:00:00. If you need to
>   identify the device, use the identifierForVendor property of UIDevice
>   instead. (Apps that need an identifier for their own advertising
>   purposes should consider using the advertisingIdentifier property of
>   ASIdentifierManager instead.)

Does QuickBlox use MAC address to have access to device's UDID? If yes maybe that's the problem.

Since uniqueIdentifier is [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/uniqueIdentifier) in iOS 7 another option is use [identifierForVendor](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor) but it has a different value.....also you can't use any parameter (UDID or UUID) in TRegisterSubscriptionWithDelegate method.

Wondering if there's another way to subscribe users for APNS with QuickBlox.

Comment: Try latest SDK version, it doesn't use MAC address for this http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS#Framework_changelog:

Answer (score 0):

It means that your users/user don't subscribed to Apple push notifications.
Maybe you unsubscribed them.

To check user's devices - go to Users module, open particular user and check this list http://qblx.co/1iC8Dtg

In this example you can see that this particular user subscribed from 2 iOS devices and can receive push notifications.

Comment: Igor Khomenko maybe it's happening since I'm updating my app to iOS 7 and UDID is now deprecated...please check my second answer